# How can a Global Variable be recognize in two different window (Java Swing GUI)

Tags: java, swing, global-variables

I've just started Studying Java GUI on Eclipse
Well I've challenged myself to create an Address Book

So here what I Got

FRONT (Swing Application Window)

```
package byDavid;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.DropMode;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Front {

private JFrame frame;
private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
protected int top = 0;               //Define Top for Stack Implementation
private static final int MAXENTRIES = 100;   //Define Array Size

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

 final AdressBookEntry[]list;  //List is declared here 


    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Front window = new Front();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Front() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Front.class.getResource("/com/sun/javafx/webkit/prism/resources/missingImage.png")));
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 357, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JList list = new JList();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    scroll.setBounds(24, 22, 185, 210);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);

    JLabel lblNameEntrees = new JLabel("Name of Entrees");
    lblNameEntrees.setBounds(50, 0, 134, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNameEntrees);
    lblNameEntrees.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.BOLD, 17));

    JButton btnAddNewEntry = new JButton("Add Entry\r\n");
    btnAddNewEntry.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            AddEntry nw = new AddEntry();
            nw.Addentry();
        }
    });
    buttonGroup.add(btnAddNewEntry);
    btnAddNewEntry.setBounds(231, 40, 100, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddNewEntry);

    JButton btnUpdateEntry = new JButton("Update Entry");
    buttonGroup.add(btnUpdateEntry);
    btnUpdateEntry.setBounds(231, 74, 99, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnUpdateEntry);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Delete Entry");
    buttonGroup.add(btnNewButton);
    btnNewButton.setBounds(231, 108, 100, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Quit");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.dispose();
        }
    });
    buttonGroup.add(btnNewButton_1);
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(231, 140, 100, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}
}
```

AddEntry (Swing Application Window) /Another A pop-Up Window

```
package byDavid;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Window.Type;
import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class AddEntry {


private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JButton btnQuit;
private JButton btnAccept;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void Addentry() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AddEntry window = new AddEntry();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public AddEntry() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {


    JTextField name  ;
    JTextField add ;
    JTextField tel ;
    JTextField email;

    String name1 = "";
    String add1 ="";
    long tel1 = 0;
    String email1 = "";


    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setType(Type.POPUP);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 369, 219);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
    lblName.setBounds(10, 11, 62, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblName);

    JLabel lblAdress = new JLabel("Adress:");
    lblAdress.setBounds(10, 42, 62, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblAdress);

    JLabel lblPhoneNumber = new JLabel("Phone Number:");
    lblPhoneNumber.setBounds(10, 77, 99, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPhoneNumber);

    JLabel lblEmailAddress = new JLabel("Email Address:");
    lblEmailAddress.setBounds(10, 108, 99, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblEmailAddress);

    name = new JTextField();
    name.setBounds(119, 15, 207, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(name);
    name.setColumns(10);

    add = new JTextField();
    add.setColumns(10);
    add.setBounds(118, 46, 208, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(add);

    tel = new JTextField();
    tel.setColumns(10);
    tel.setBounds(119, 81, 207, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tel);

    email = new JTextField();
    email.setColumns(10);
    email.setBounds(119, 112, 207, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(email);

    btnQuit = new JButton("Close");
    btnQuit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.dispose();
        }
    });

    btnQuit.setBounds(237, 148, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnQuit);

    btnAccept = new JButton("Accept");
    btnAccept.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            name.getText();
            add.getText();
            tel.getText();
            email.getText();
            frame.dispose();

               //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
               //I want the Text to be Assigned to a Variable
               //So I will put these code here

         /*
    AddressBookEntry entry = new AddressBookEntry (name, add, tel, email);
    list[top] = entry;
    top++;

         */

         //Yes list, top is getting the error here.. and It confuses me why?

        }
    });
    btnAccept.setBounds(119, 148, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAccept);
    frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]      {frame.getContentPane(), lblName, lblAdress, lblPhoneNumber, lblEmailAddress,     textField, textField_1, textField_2, textField_3}));
}

}
```

How can I declare list and top to be recognized by the Add Entry Pop-up Window?

Because It must be red by this class so I can show it in the Jlist later on ..

AdressBookEntry Class (This is where the temp of the variables go, and'll be called)

```
package byDavid;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AdressBookEntry {



private JTextField name;
private JTextField add;
private JTextField  tel;
private JTextField email;


public AdressBookEntry(JTextField name, JTextField add, JTextField tel, JTextField email){
this.name =  name;
this.add = add;
this.tel = tel;
this.email = email;

}



public JTextField getName(){
return name;
}

public void changeName(JTextField name){
this.name = name;
}

public JTextField getAddress(){
return add;
}

public void changeAddress(JTextField add){
this.add = add;
}

public JTextField getTelNumber(){
return tel;
}

public void changeTelNUmbe(JTextField tel){
this.tel = tel;
}

public JTextField getEmailAdd(){
return email;
}

public void changeEmailAdd(JTextField email){
this.email = email;
}

}
```

I've searched many post,blog and etc. but I can't find specific answer.
Please Explain it to me clearly, because I'm quite confused in Declaring the two, and their specific errors..

Comment: Pass the list or the common object in the constructor or add setters and set it to both.

Comment: Yes I'll do that.. But can you help me on the Global Declaring Problem? Top and List  ..

Comment: I see, instead of creating the anonymous implementation of the Runnable interface you can actually write a class that implements Runnable with a constructor where you could pass the object in the constructor after creating it in the main method.

Comment: Can you give me an example process .. I can't briefly follow sorry :'( 
I mean in Accordance to Swing :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final AdressBookEntry[] list;  //List is declared here    
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new FrontRunner(list));
}

private class FrontRunner implements Runnable {
    private AdressBookEntry[] list;
    public FrontRunner(AdressBookEntry[] list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Front window = new Front();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay Im trying it now and im getting some little trouble.. but wait ill debug it a bit, and update you :D

Comment: @CodingSymphony I assumed you also initialize the list in main, not only declare, right?

Comment: I actually tried to copy the way you code there.. But Like my problem said I t is still not recognize...   And anyway the other error was "list" cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @CodingSymphony Yes, when you want to use it inside Front then you also need to add it to its constructor.

Comment: in accordance to your process , as i've narrowed it down, "list" needs to be initialized   "But" If initialized the (new FrontRunner(list)) will have syntax error..